# Ggplot : How to select a string value for in a graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

This is my problem :
I want to make a lottery graph in R. I have a dataset called "loto" with 2000 different draw.
I want to make this type of graph, but, per day. I have 3 different days in "jour_de_tirage" -> Monday, Wednesday and Saturday.

--> I want to select the string "Monday" ("Lundi")
[image: r]

This is the code of the previous graph, but I don't know where I can add the filter to filter it by day.

```
 loto %>% 
  select(boule_1, boule_2, boule_3, boule_4, boule_5) %>%
  gather(key = key, value = value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = key))
```

I tried this :

```
 loto %>%
select(jour_de_tirage) %>%
group_by(loto$boule_1, loto$boule_2, loto$boule_3, loto$boule_4, loto$boule_5) %>%
ggplot(x = jour_de_tirage["Lundi"], y = numbers[1:49]) + geom_bar()
ggtitle("Monday Lottery Stats")
```

I have some errors with this code and I don't find the issue...

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: why don't you filter before the select statement? Or otherwise, you could also put jour_de_tirage in the select statement, exclude it from the gather and than use it in a facetwrap to get a plot by day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of @Annet's comment, you should add `filter` before calling `select` and `gather`:

```
loto %>% 
  filter(jour_de_tirage == "Lundi") %>%
  select(boule_1, boule_2, boule_3, boule_4, boule_5) %>%
  gather(key = key, value = value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = key))
```